# incorrect edge direction in infoviz's Force Directed Graph

Tags: infovis

I am trying to show force graph like "graphnode6.0-----> graphnode0.0  -------> graphnode15.0 " but when i contruct json object i always get "graphnode6.0------> graphnode0.0 <---------graphnode15.0"
My JSON object is

```
var json = [
{
  "adjacencies": [  
  {
      "nodeTo": "graphnode15.0", 
      "data": {"$type":"arrow",
      "$direction":"['graphnode0.0','graphnode15.0']"}
    }  
  ], 
  "data": {
    '$color': "#83548B", 
    '$type': "circle"
  }, 
  "id": "graphnode0.0", 
  "name": "graphnode0.0"
},
{
  "adjacencies": [    
     {
      "nodeTo": "graphnode0.0", 
      "data": {"$type":"arrow",
      "$direction":"['graphnode6.0','graphnode0.0']"}
    }], 
  "data": {
    "$color": "#83548B", 
    "$type": "circle"
  }, 
  "id": "graphnode6.0", 
  "name": "graphnode6.0"
}
```

];

Am i making any mistake in this JSON structure ?
Thanks
Sumit

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but thanks to your quick demo, I think I've managed to fix both our issues :)

Use double quote inside your direction block.

```
"$direction":["graphnode1", "nodeZ"]
```

When I tried with single quotes

```
"$direction":['graphnode1', 'nodeZ']
```

the arrows would render in one direction only.
Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a string for the `$direction` property.

```
"$direction":"['graphnode6.0','graphnode0.0']"
```

It should be an array. Like this:

```
"$direction":["graphnode6.0","graphnode0.0"]
```

[See this example code.](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/RGraph/example2.code.html)